# How to dynamically change card number input mask (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android, input-mask

I need to change input mask dynamically. For example, if user inputs 13 digits then one mask, if 20 then another.

I am using redmadrobot:inputmask. Here is my code

```
ArrayList<String> affineFormats = new ArrayList<>();     
        affineFormats.add("[0000] [000] [000] [000]");
        affineFormats.add("[0000] [0000] [0000] [0000] [0000]");
        String format = "[0000] [000] [000] [000]";
        MaskedTextChangedListener listener = new PolyMaskTextChangedListener(
                format,
                affineFormats,
                true,
                etCardNumber,
                null,
                new MaskedTextChangedListener.ValueListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(boolean b, String s) {
                   //here some code
                    }
                });
        etCardNumber.addTextChangedListener(listener);
```

But when I enter the card number is used the last one added is  formatted according to *affineFormats*. Please help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you are using a slightly outdated version of our library.

In v.4 we already have `PolyMaskTextChangedListener` merged with the `MaskedTextChangedListener`. We also introduced a handy utility called [`AffinityCalculationStrategy`](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/wiki/2.1-Affine-Masks#affinity-calculation-strategy), which might actually help with your problem.

From our [Wiki](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android/wiki/2.1-Affine-Masks):

> **Affinity calculation strategy**
>
> Affinity is an integer number, which represents the similarity between the input and the current mask. Thus, the mask with the highest affinity is picked to format the output.
>
> Affinity calculation strategy is a text field listener property allowing to alter the math behind the affinity calculation.

...

> `AffinityCalculationStrategy.EXTRACTED_VALUE_CAPACITY`— this strategy comes in handy when the mask format radically changes depending on the *extracted value* length.

(and your digits are the extracted value)